# Expected Value and Variance Questiob

Tags: probability

If $\operatorname{E}[X]=1$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X)=5$, find:

a) $\operatorname{E}[(2+X)^2]$

b) $\operatorname{Var}(4+3X)$

So for part (b) I used an identity from the text to get $\operatorname{Var}(4+3X)=(3^2)\operatorname{Var}(X)=45$.

As for part (a), I'm a little stumped

Comment: Try "foiling" out $(2+X)^2$.

Comment: Alright, so now I have X^2 + 4X + 4

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for part (b) is correct. For part (a), just some math manipulation.

It might be helpful to first rewrite $E\left((2+X)^2\right)=E\left(X^2 + 4X + 4\right)$.

Then, using rules of expectations, you can rewrite $E\left(X^2 + 4X + 4\right)$ as $E\left(X^2\right)+E\left(4X\right)+E\left(4\right)$.

Rules of expectations also tell us that $E(4X) = 4E(X)$, so at this point, plug in what you know: $$E\left(X^2\right)+4E\left(X\right)+E\left(4\right) = E\left(X^2\right) + 4*1 + 4 = E\left(X^2\right) + 8$$

You then want to note the relationship between variance and expectation: $Var(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2$

You can plug in your given values, and you should be good from there. I.e. $$[Var(X) = 5] =  E(X^2) - [1]^2$$

So $E(X^2)=6$, which gives you that $E\left((2+X)^2\right)= 8+6 = 14$.

Hope that helps!

Comment: awesome, thanks so much!